# Cannot loop through pages from Json response using Google Reseller API

Tags: java, json, google-api

I am new to Json and trying to extract data. The Json response includes a NextPageToken and i have to set it manually to get the next pages, etc.

How can i loop through all of the pages using Java ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the command in a loop, setting the request pageToken to the nextPageToken as long as it exists. For instance:

```
do {
    Users page = request.execute();
    allUsers.addAll(page.getUsers());
    request.setPageToken(page.getNextPageToken());
} while (request.getPageToken() != null
        && request.getPageToken().length() > 0);
```

This example uses the Directory service from the Admin SDK, but the method works for other APIs as well.